Use of "Thru" in business letters
I have seen some letters that have "Thru" in the inside address. Like in this letter:
02 March 2015
"Thru: BULBUL R. TORRES"
In all letters that I've found that have that, it's always found after the inside address. What is it used for? I think it is used to state a flow of information, or the person being stated is already aware of the content of the letter. But I'm not quite sure of it. So... How is it really used?

I've never seen this usage in British business letters. It's clear from the style that  this is an Asian version of English.

I have never seen this in US business letters either.

I found the answer on a Philippines site. Which is where your writer is from. –

The letter would not go direct to the addressee but through another party first.
In the OP's example, the letter would go through
BULBUL R. TORRES to keep this person informed before being directed to the addressee.


PREPOSITION B2
If you do something through someone else, they take the necessary action for you.



Would that necessarily mean that BULBUL R. TORRES would be the one who will send the letter to the "real" recipient?

Yes, that's right.

That is what most English speakers would guess it must mean. However, according to Lambie's answer, that is not what it means in the Philippines, where it is actually used.

This usage is from the Philippines:

Addressee Line. Addressee line shall be in bold and all capital
letters. It follows the Memorandum Line by one (1) line space. Below
are variations to use in the Addressee line:
• FOR shall be used for a
memorandum to be sent to an official in rank higher than or equal to
the signatory.
• TO shall be used for a memorandum to be sent to an
officialjemployee/s in rank lower than the signatory.
• FOR/TO shall
be used for a memorandum to be sent to officials and employees with
different ranks (higher and lower ranks). Do not add ALL after FOR/TO.
• THRU shall be used for a memorandum to be sent to officials and
employees to let them be aware.
• ATTENTION shall be used to direct
the letter to a particular person in an organization.

Philippines usage by a government agency
[Bolding is mine.]
In the West, we don't use that. We use something like:
To: All staff

It sounds most like "CC" (originally "carbon copy", but now just "send to people who are not the recipient to make them aware"). The "all capital letters" is not customary in the UK or US (or Canada, Ireland, Australia, New Zealand) as far as I know.

@ColinFine Hear, hear. I am just reproducing the Philippino letter. It is not carbon copy. It says clearly what it means in that letter. It means sent to someone or to others.

Two downvotes, really?
